# contact form showing my host address. when i got message

Tags: php, contacts

hello i have using a contact form when i get any mail from my  client i saw my host name showing in mail from. like  when i saw saw before open my mail there showing name who send and from where i saw there showing my host name geologicsdz@host.dramaclassesonline.com.
but in mail everything ok.
so i like to change host name where must be show from his email address

```
    $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
$replyto='my@email.com';
if($post)
    {

$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$business = stripslashes($_POST['business']);
$comments = stripslashes($_POST['comments']);
$phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
$howhear = stripslashes($_POST['howhear']);

$to=$toemail.','.$replyto;
$error = '';
$headers="";
$headers.="Reply-to:$replyto\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\n";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n".$headers;



if(!$error)
    {

$messages="<h2>From: $name has contacted Geological Solutions</h2>";
$messages.="<h4>Name: $name </h4>";
$messages.="<h4>Email: $email </h4>";
$messages.="<h4>Phone: $phone </h4>";
$messages.="<h4>How did you hear about us?: $howhear </h4>";
$messages.="<h4> Comments: $comments </h4>";


    $mail = mail($to,$name,$messages,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were in the correct path but have overwritten your headers. here is the fix for it

```
$headers="";
$headers.="Reply-to:$replyto\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n".$headers;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n".$headers;` ? dot missing in front of the equal sign.

Comment: @Fred i left it be because what i understood he may want the content-type header to be the first